# Configuring AppData Inspector for SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: core-service

Frank van Puffelen's [AppData Inspector](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/appdata.aspx) lets you browse App Data using a command-line tool.

It comes with a XML configuration file that defines the WCF service client endpoint. For a Tridion 2011 setup this looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
            <!-- removed for brevity -->
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://localhost/webservices/CoreService.svc/basicHttp_2010"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp_2010"
              contract="Tridion.ICoreService2010" name="basicHttp_2010" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In Tridion 2013, I understand the endpoints were updated. Rather than an endpoint address with `http://localhost/webservices/CoreService.svc`, we now reference a specific version as in: `http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc`

The [documentation describes the endpoints](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/undefined/undefined/GUID-58B7A994-053D-45A3-B875-3BC79A294765), but I'm not sure on attributes like `contract`.

Trying the following:

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/basicHttp"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp_2010"
      contract="Tridion.ICoreService2010" name="basicHttp_2010" />
</client>
```

Gives the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.ActionNotSupportedException:
>   The message with Action
>   'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2010/ICoreSe
>   rvice2010/ReadAllApplicationData' cannot be processed at the receiver,
>   due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may
>   be because of either  a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the
>   sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and  receiver have the
>   same contract and the same binding (including security requirements,
>   e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Can we use the AppData inspector on a 2013 setup by updating `AppData.exe.config`?

**Edit**:

Using the following:

```
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/basicHttp_2010"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp_2010"
          contract="Tridion.ICoreService2010" name="basicHttp_2010" />
    </client>
```

Gives:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
>   There was no  endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/basicHttp_2010 that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   ---> System .Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpC
>   hannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---

**Update**: based on Rick's explanation, to make the AppData Companion work for Tridion 2011 SP1 and later, we need to update the Service Reference and code.

So this endpoint (with code and service changes) works:

```
<endpoint address="http://train1/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/basicHttp"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp1"
                contract="Tridion.ICoreService" name="basicHttp1" />
```

I added the [updated project and .exe. to SDL Community](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/m/mediagallery/939) and placed the updated project in the [TridionWorld repository](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/AppData%20Companion).

Comment: In your service endpoint address is: http://localhost/webservices/CoreService.svc/basicHttp_2010 however in your client endpoint address is http://localhost/webservices/CoreService.svc/basicHttp, which are not matching. My understanding is both should be same.

Comment: Thanks, Hiren. It looks like I don't have `CoreService.svc` in the folder for the webservices IIS Web Application (just `CoreService2011.svc`, `CoreService2012.svc`, `CoreService2013.svc`, and `ImportExportService2013.svc`). Maybe SDL Tridion 2013 (SP1) does not ship with the vanilla `CoreService.svc` anymore? I don't think basicHttp_2010 applies for CoreService2011.svc--I added the error from trying it to my answer.

Comment: I'm thinking the answer here is "no, you can't use the AppData inspector with just a configuration change." Either we update the code to use a more recent endpoint or hack 2013 SP1 to use the old endpoint. I'll accept an answer if someone can confirm `CoreService.svc` was deprecated (and in which Tridion version).

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's a working version of the AppData Inspector in the PowerTools.

Comment: Command line tools are the ultimate power tools. ;-)

Comment: I was actually troubleshooting the Item Comments PowerTools extension using the AppData Inspector and ran into this while also trying AppData Companion. I <3 AppData.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Service endpoints and contracts are side-by-side versioned. That is: with each new Tridion (point) release, we introduce new contracts and endpoints, but the old ones are also kept (hence the version numbers in the URLs).
Clients compiled against an older contract will remain working without recompiling or changing the endpoint URL (as a matter of fact, if you only change the URL to a newer version, you'll get the error you encountered).

This side-by-side versioning policy was introduced in the 2011 SP1 release (2011 contracts/endpoints). The 2010 contracts stem from the 2011 GA release and these were  not forward compatible (it wouldn't be able to deal with future data contract changes). That is why the 2010 contracts/endpoints were dropped in 2013 SP1 and why you will have to change tools that use these 2010 contracts/endpoints.

Comment: Perfect. In Visual Studio I was able to replace the old Web Reference with a new one (using localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc?wsdl). The tool worked after replacing all references to `CoreService2010Client` with `CoreServiceClient` and then using the `basicHttp1` endpoint. I like how the code itself is now "version agnostic" without any version years.

Comment: Nice. You could also have used the OOTB Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll  (provided since 2011SP1 release) instead of a Web Reference.

Comment: And note that although the client code now looks "version agnostic" (no version numbers in type names), it is not -- you still compile the code for a specific contract version and should use the appropriate Core Service endpoints (URLs) for that version.   The reason why the version numbers were removed from the client-side types is to facilitate migration to a newer version (although this remains an explicit, manual action).

Comment: Good points. Indeed I explicitly had to remove one Web Reference and replace it with a new one against a newer endpoint. Ah, and I forgot about the OOTB client dll--I'll leave that as an exercise for the next AppData Companion contributor. ;-)