# Read appdata in GUI extension

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

For one of the requirement, we would like to store configuration data for the GUI extension in the appdata. While looking online for help only thing that I found was that I can read appdata using core service: [Access appdata](https://tridionfanboy.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/sdl-tridion-2011-appdata/)

However, did not find any way of reading in GUI extension using Aguila. Can you please suggest if there any way I can read app data using Aguila.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen this post as well, perhaps it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801301/how-to-set-tridion-applicationdata-using-anguilla-javascript

It is somewhat outdated (very likely written for 2011) but in principle it still applies for 2013.

Comment: If there is no way to read appdata from the GUI extension then this is the only option.

Comment: I don't think there is any Anguilla API call that reads appdata directly, no - so you do need to create a service for it.

Answer (score 7):

When you say "*the*" appdata do you mean the extension relates to components and you want to store the data in the component appdata? (I guess one good reason to do this is that it could be content ported when a component is moved through the environment(s)?)

As Nuno states - there is no direct Anguilla API which is what you *seem* to be asking for.

Perhaps as part of developing your extension you would be best advised to use/update the WCF Web Service presented [here](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/m/mediagallery/939); it's a great start-point and uses an XML configuration file that defines the WCF service client endpoint!

Note that as you're using 2013-SP1 you will also need this reference point: [Configuring AppData Inspector for SDL Tridion 2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11600/configuring-appdata-inspector-for-sdl-tridion-2013/11610#11610)